# Matrix exponential of an LTI system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-exponential, transition-matrix

Is there any direct proof to show that if eigenvalues of an LTI system are negative then the transition matrix ( or matrix exponential with respect to time) *e^{At}* decays to zero when *t* goes to infinity? An straightforward case is when the system is diagonalizable.

Comment: What do you mean by 'direct? What demonstration did you find that is not satisfying you?

Comment: even if it is not diagonalizable, you can show that the stable Jordan blocks also decay and you are done.

Comment: Thank you Jordan. By 'direct' I meant an approach that does not involve diagonalization method that leads to 'Jordan blocks'. However, as you said, the decaying 'Jordan blocks' completes the proof.